# Is there a way for Google Workspace admin to set "send mail as" the original recipient in GMail?

Tags: gmail

Using a GMail's routing feature within Google Workspace for Business, I am able to set forwarding emails to 1st@my.org to 2nd@my.org. But replying to that email on 2nd@my.org's email editor (on GMail webapp on my.org), the recipient of it sees the `from` field as 2nd@my.org, not 1st@my.org.

Is there a way for an admin in the above scenario to force 2nd@my.org to reply as 1st@my.org for the emails that are sent to 1st@my.org then somehow forwarded to 2nd@my.org?

I know each user can setup their GMail editor to customize `send mail as` (e.g. [webapps.stackexchange.com#14902](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/can-gmail-automatically-base-send-from-address-on-the-to-address) and [webapps.stackexchange.com#131235](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/131235/gmail-alias-automatically-send-mail-as-alias-when-alias-is-recipient)), but I'm asking admin's feature so that each user doesn't have to bother customizing their editor.

I'm aware that Google Workspace comes with multiple routing options. For now, I'm using `Default Routing` but other routing option can be considered. I'm an admin in a small org that uses Google Workspace for nonprofit.

---

UPDATE 2024/03/26 To clarify, the solution doesn't have to be implemented in Google Workspace's rounting feature.

Comment: Many email clients do this, but you dont usd a forward. Instead grab enails from both addresses. These can br displayed together or separately

Comment: No. What you are asking for can't be done.  You need to manage "send as" options within the mail client. It isn't related to email routing.

Comment: @Blindspots Thanks. As I updated OP, the solution can be implemented anywhere. I'm not limiting to email routing.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate things are being discussed.

The first is **routing** which you are using to redirect messages received by your organization. When you do this, Google adds routing, tracking, and verification information to the message headers that reflect the change, but  outside of allowing custom text to be appended to the subject line (historically common for SPAM flags) and  any additional custom headers you may have configured, the underlying message left unchanged.

Since you administer the Google Workplace Domain as well as the local users, as a superUser, you are free to route/redirect/discard your organization's incoming messages.

Users have the ability to set "send as" addresses/aliases from within their Gmail account and also default to always replying from the same address by selecting "**Reply from the same address the message was sent to**" as the default behavior in [Gmail > Settings > Accounts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts).
S
Setting up a "send as" address requires users to be authenticated and the new address to be verified.

Simulating the behavior of a "send as" alias" on behalf of users amounts to tampering with messages in transit. It entails modifying the message to forge the sender information. This is difficult to achieve without running your own non-Gmail servers and significant expertise and is still likely to trip security flags from recipient mail servers.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is both `subject` and `from` fields are in the headers of an email. If so, why modification to the former is ok but to the latter should be considered as tampering?

Comment: @IsaacS The characterization as *tampering* could apply to modifying the subject as well if we are discussing the outgoing messages. The sender controls their info and can send from an alternate address if they so choose.  The recipient has a legitimate expectation that the message they receive has not been tampered with in transit.  On the face of it, the goal is plainly to deceive the recipient by interfering with the message.